# Ember.js app offline behavior

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember app that interacts with a rails app using the ember-rails gem.

I would like to use the localStorage adapter to store a list of products once they have been downloaded from the server over the rest api.

Then, if the app is offline, ember can use the localStorage data rather than asking the rails app for the data.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: one way may be creating you own model objects rather than using ember-data...

Comment: I would like to use the features of ember-data however. I want to be able to seamlessly load data from a REST API into a bunch of ember model classes without having to write any of the code that does that. Is it even possible to switch out the data store in your app during its lifetime?

Answer (score 3):

I have done something along these lines.  This doesn't handle when to refresh for caching, and things like that.  But, it will provide you with a way to initially load up items from localStorage and then if the network is not available, the content will just stay as the local data.  You can of course expand this greatly to handle your needs.

```
App.PhotoCategories = Ember.Object.extend

  init: ->
    @_super()
    @loadPhotoCategories

  loadPhotoCategories: () ->
    # load cached categories from local storage
    @set 'content', @getFromCache("photoCategories")

    if @content?
      if @content.length == 0
         $.ajax
           type: "POST"      
           url: "/api/getCategories"
           success: (data) =>
             if !data.error
             @set 'content', []

             for category in data
               @pushObject category

              # save categories to local storage
              @saveToCache("photoCategories", @content)             

  saveToCache: (key, data) ->
    if @supportsHtml5Storage()
      localStorage.setItem(key + '_LastUpdatedAt', new Date())
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data))
      true
    else
      false

  getFromCache: (key) ->
    if @supportsHtml5Storage()
      data = localStorage[key]

      if data?
        JSON.parse(localStorage[key])
      else
        null
    else
      null

  supportsHtml5Storage: ->
    try
      return "localStorage" of window and window["localStorage"] isnt null
    catch e
      return false
```